# Import csv comma separated values into Table as multiple rows

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a .csv file that looks something like this:

```
test1; A,B
test2; B
test3; A,B,C
```

What I want is a table like:

```
test1  A
test1  B
test2  B
test3  A
test3  B
test3  C
```

What I've already achieved:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path.csv' 
INTO TABLE table1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(col1, col2);
```

But it skips all lines, that have multiple comma separated values in the second field...

I'm sorry, if this was already asked, but I'm completely struggling to find a solution for days...

Comment: Not something load data can handle. Either fix your data before load (the preferred approach) or load then split.

Comment: You have a 1:n relation and want to "unfold" into 1:1, but in multiple rows. I agree with @P.Salmon that you need to change the data.  I would do this with perl, autoit3, python or similar. It's interesting to know if you ever have duplicate "testX" ?

Comment: This doesn't look like a csv

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following. In part because I'm still using a rather old version of MySQL, I have a utility table of integers (ints) with values 0-9...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(my_string VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('test1; A,B'),
('test2; B'),
('test3; A,B,C');

SELECT DISTINCT
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_string,';',1)  test
     , TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_string,';',-1),',',i+1),',',-1)) vals 
  FROM my_table
     , ints;

+-------+------+
| test  | vals |
+-------+------+
| test1 | A    |
| test2 | B    |
| test3 | A    |
| test1 | B    |
| test3 | B    |
| test3 | C    |
+-------+------+
```